# I am trying to do a search filter with mongo and api, but it getting error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mern

I am trying to search a file when I type something in the form. first I do POST and save it, then in the other form, I search , if the input is equal that I have in the database, I fecth it, else It do nothing .

I am getting "not find" when I execute it in postman. Can someone help me? I aprecciate

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require ("../models/Post");

router.get("/" ,async (req,res ) => {
    try {
        const findPost = await Post.findOne(); 
        
            if ( req.body.post === findPost) {
                res.status(200).json(findPost);
            } else {
                res.status(401).json("not find")
            }

        
    } catch {
        res.status(500).json("not correct");
    }
```

this is the post Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema)
```

Comment: Can u show your `POST` schema? And what are the keys using which you want to search your post? Note that you must pass some condition in `findOne` otherwise it will select the oldest post in your database.

Comment: @Kanhaiya I post it in the question now. I saw some videos doing only with react in youtube, but I am trying to do it with mern

Comment: So I am assuming that you are trying to find a post which should match exactly with the content that is in `post` field of your `postSchema`. Your Post schema has 2 main fields: 1. `_id`, 2. `post`(string). Assuming that your `req.body.post` is a string, you can do it with ----> ` const findPost = await Post.findOne({post:req.body.post}); if(findPost){res.status(200).json(findPost);} else{res.status(401).json("not find")} ` . Let me know if it worked!

Comment: @Kanhaiya It worked, congrats

Comment: I am glad that it worked. I have written a more detailed solution in answer.Have a look at it!

Comment: @Kanhaiya I am trying to do it now in the front part with react. Do you know how can I do it? I tried but it is not working

Comment: Yes i have answered there. Do accept answers if they were helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// A simple solution
const findPost = await Post.findOne({post:req.body.post}); 
if(findPost){
  res.status(200).json(findPost);
} 
else{
  res.status(401).json("not found");
}
```

2.If you are willing to filter all posts matching a regEx

```js
// If you want to match pattern disregarding cashes

const regEx = new RegExp(req.body.post, "i");
const allPosts = await Post.find({post: regEx});
if(allPosts && allPosts.length){
   res.status(200).json(allPosts);
}
else{
   res.status(401).json("not found");
}
```